# Error while publishing message to FIFO SNS topic through boto3 code

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sns, fifo

I am getting an error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: 'Invalid parameter: The MessageGroupId parameter is required for FIFO topics'.

```
logging.info(f"Preparing to the event notification to the topic {target_topic}")
target_topic_arn = None
session = boto3.Session(region_name=region)
sns_client = session.client("sns")
client = boto3.client('sns',
                      region_name=region, verify=False)
response = client.list_topics()
topics = response["Topics"]
for topic in topics:
    # ('SNS_data', topic)
    if target_topic in topic['TopicArn']:
        target_topic_arn = topic['TopicArn']

logging.info(f"target_topic_arn for which message will be sent {target_topic_arn}")
response = sns_client.publish(
    TopicArn=target_topic_arn,
    Message=message
)
return response
```

If I add the MessageGroupId parameter to the method then it throws different error like below. I have updated boto3 to 1.21.0 and other dependent libraries

```
response = sns_client.publish(
    TopicArn=target_topic_arn,
    Message=message,
    MessageGroupId="some"
)
```

```
 "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"MessageGroupId\", must be one of: TopicArn, TargetArn, PhoneNumber, Message, Subject, MessageStructure, MessageAttributes"
```

Please advise me if anything missing.